# Python - How do I put results of strings in an if else in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

let's say `rand_word` is string = `'petite'`
and `guess` is a user input of a single char

```
for char in rand_word:
    if char in guess:
        print(char,end='')
    else:
        print('_',end="")
```

in the code above if I typed the letter 'e' as my input
it will output this

```
_e___e
```

My problem is how do I put this output in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Put your characters in a list and join it with `str.join()`:

```
result = []
for char in rand_word:
    if char in guess:
        result.append(char)
    else:
        result.append('_')
result = ''.join(result)
```

Using a conditional expression and a list comprehension, you can put this all on one line:

```
result = ''.join([c if c in guess else '_' for c in rand_word])
```

Comment: Hi, 
I am making a hangman game using python, I had used the code you provided and It worked.

But my problem is that whenever I input a letter it will output let say in 'petite' if I input the letter 'e' the output is>> _e___e
But when I input another letter lets say letter 't' it will output >> __t_t_

What I want is the first output is also included like this whenever I get a correct letter >> _e_t_te

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/HrV27pxT

Comment: @rccnls27: It's best if you put that in a *new* question; comments are not a good place to ask about new problems you encounter once your current problem is solved. You'll need to remember the previous guesses too; make a list or set `guesses` and add each `guess` letter to that, then use `if char in guesses`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
result = [char if char in guess else "_" for char in rand_word]
str_result = "".join(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, maybe

```
to_print = ""
for char in rand_word:
    if char in guess:
        to_print += char
    else:
        to_print += '_'
print(to_print)
```

The million dollar question being why might this not be a good idea...